# How to execute code in docker on wsl2 using VScode

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using wsl2-ubuntu.
I want to run and access the `python` code in a docker container on wsl2 using vscode.

Is there a way I can run the code via vscode?

I've tried run it on command line, but I want to run code in VScode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or using coderunner)

Comment: Read the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python